Is there a form of regularized regression that's equivalent to maximum likelihood together with model selection by information criteria?
AIC
We often use stuff like AIC for model selection:
$$
AIC = 2k - 2\ln(L\hat)
$$
where $k$ is the number of parameters and $L̂$ is the maximized likelihood function.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion
Typically this involves fitting multiple models and selecting the one with minimum AIC.
Issues with discrete model selection
This discrete approach seems suboptimal since we need to

Fit multiple models

Search over a discrete space of model configurations (which quickly becomes intractable)


Idea
Instead of this discrete optimization, could we have a differentiable version of AIC that allows for gradient-based optimization etc?
The bit in that formula that's not "differentiable" is the term $k$ (number of nonzero parameters).
So suppose we replace this discrete count with a continuous multivariable function
For each parameter $βᵢ$ in the model, we could use a function like:
$$G(βᵢ) = 1 - exp(-βᵢ²/σ²)$$
This function has the properties:
As $|βᵢ| → ∞$, $G(βᵢ) → 1$ (parameter "counts" as 1)
As $βᵢ → 0$, $G(βᵢ) → 0$ (parameter "counts" as 0)
(Smooth, differentiable transition between these states)
The total continuous parameter count would be:
$k_{continuous} = Σᵢ G(βᵢ)$
NOTE: you would not do regular maximum likelihood here; you'd take the AIC with the continuous parameter count and optimize that (which would essentially be the likelihood multiplied by an exponential of the "continuous parameter count")
Idea, more detail
In general you could use something like a multivariate Gaussian kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel (ie the Gaussian kernel but with a non-identity covariance matrix that gives different "exchange rates" between different parameters)
$G(\boldsymbol{\beta}) = 1 - \exp\left(-\boldsymbol{\beta}^{\top}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\beta}\right)$
ie
$k_{\text{continuous}} = \sum_{i} \left(1 - \exp\left(-\boldsymbol{\beta}_i^{\top}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\beta}_i\right)\right)$

(For comparison, usual regularization methods;
Lasso:
$\min\left\{\frac{1}{N}\|y-X\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2 + \lambda\|\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_1\right\}$
Ridge Regression:
$\min\left\{\frac{1}{N}\|y-X\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2 + \lambda\|\boldsymbol{\beta}\|_2^2\right\}$
But with a potentially better-motivated penalty term (for free-ish).
And in particular, it seems like the AIC and BIC formulas would suggest the parameter penalty should be multiplicative (although you might get these as a first-order approximation to the multiplicative case?)
Questions

Is this already a thing?

How would this compare theoretically to existing regularization methods?

Are there already ways of making AIC, BIC etc "continuous"?


